# call asp.net server method from <a href="tel:##" Click Event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am using a touch to call link in an asp.net application and want to make a server side call prior to executing the touch calling link itself. the idea is that the link would also call a method on the code behind to log the click event.

**html**

```
<a href="tel:+1800229900">Call us free!</a>
```

**c# code behind**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string logClick(string candContactedID)
        {
            try
            {
                /*
                insert into DB currDateTime, candContactedID
                 */
                return "call logged for candidate = " + candContactedID;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                return errorMessage + ex.InnerException;
            }
        }
```

do I need jquery client code code or is there a .net trick here to magically wire things up?

Comment: It is trivial to bind an event handler that makes an ajax request. What is the specific problem or question?

Comment: Off-topic, but the hoops you're jumping through in your `catch` handler are unnecessary. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring.aspx) (emphasis mine): *The default implementation of ToString obtains the name of the class that threw the current exception, the message,* ***the result of calling ToString on the inner exception,*** *and the result of calling Environment.StackTrace.*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi probably there for the OP's (original) intent (some db call commented out)...

Comment: I want to execute a server side call to save to sql some data as well as enact the calling option from mobile devise once clicking the href="tel" link